# Packet gen DPDK master lcore cannot be used for a port error

Tags: dpdk

I am facing the issue of master lcore cannot be used for  a port while trying to run the default configuration of run.py in packet gen dpdk. When i run the same command using sudo, it gives the error that the packet gen is not available. I have searched all over the internet and did not came across anyone facing such error. kindly guide me about this error. I am attaching the screenshot of the error.[Master lcore not available for port error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga1fC.png)
[default configuration file part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEgfJ.png)
[default configuration file part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LELL0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can not pass the master core as RX or TX core for any port for pktgen. Since this will be running periodic handler for CLI and other services.

Please change the core to port mapping `[0:1].0-3` to `[1].0`. This will make port 0 to use core 1 to run RX and TX.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. The master lcore problem is solved, but I have faced another issue that says did not find any ports to use. I am sorry I am new to this field and dont know that much about it. Any help will be much Appreciated.

Comment: for the current ticket, please accept and upvote. For your new problem, please open a new request with details `lshw -c network -businfo`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As a new contributor am not able to publicly up vote your answer. I have up voted it but it does not display publicly for now. Once I gain enough reputations, the up vote would be showed automatically. Once again thank you for your answer. I have posted my new issue in a separate request with details.

Comment: ok you can accept the answer. so it is marked as closed